# Visual C++ 6.0 - Possible Conversion Loss of Data (Warning C4244)

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I am using quite an old compiler, and I believe the compiler has made a bit of a mistake in its warning diagnosis.

```
    typedef unsigned char uint8_t;          // 8-bit byte
    typedef unsigned int uint32_t;          // 32-bit word (change to "long" for 16-bit machines)
    
    typedef struct _sha256_ctx_t
    {
        uint8_t             data[64];
        uint32_t            data_len;
        unsigned __int64    bit_len;        // unsigned long long
        uint32_t            state[8];
    } sha256_ctx_t;


void crypto_sha256_final(sha256_ctx_t *ctx, uint8_t *digest)
{
    uint32_t i;

    i = ctx->data_len;

    // Append to the padding the total message's length in bits and transform.
    ctx->bit_len += ctx->data_len * 8;
    ctx->data[63] = ctx->bit_len; // LINE 156 IS HERE!
    ctx->data[62] = ctx->bit_len >> 8;
    ctx->data[61] = ctx->bit_len >> 16;
    ctx->data[60] = ctx->bit_len >> 24;
    ctx->data[59] = ctx->bit_len >> 32;
    ctx->data[58] = ctx->bit_len >> 40;
    ctx->data[57] = ctx->bit_len >> 48;
    ctx->data[56] = ctx->bit_len >> 56; // LINE 163 IS HERE!

    local_sha256_transform(ctx, ctx->data);

    // Since this implementation uses little endian byte ordering and SHA uses big endian,
    // reverse all the bytes when copying the final state to the output digest.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        digest[i]      = (ctx->state[0] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        digest[i + 4]  = (ctx->state[1] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        digest[i + 8]  = (ctx->state[2] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        digest[i + 12] = (ctx->state[3] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        digest[i + 16] = (ctx->state[4] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        digest[i + 20] = (ctx->state[5] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        digest[i + 24] = (ctx->state[6] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        digest[i + 28] = (ctx->state[7] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
    }
}
```

That code results in this error (from lines 156 to 163):

> SHA256.cpp(156) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data

I guess this old compiler doesn't realise that adding it with 0xFF narrows the result to a byte. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get around the false warning?

Original code source: https://programmer.group/61737ba233df9.html

Comment: Can you clarify which exact line in the shown code is "adding it with 0xFF"?

Comment: Sure, I've added that for you.

Comment: A 64-bit number won't fit into an 8-bit number without losing data. It's not a false warning.

Comment: **Why** are you using this ancient, bug-ridden, unmaintained compiler? Do yourself a favour, kick it to the curb and use a modern compiler.

Comment: Well, yes, it does look the compiler doesn't understand this, that's it.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix it? I have my reasons why I need to use this particular compiler.

Comment: — Honestly, the fix is to use a minimally working compiler. If you actually have valid reasons for using an irredeemably broken one all we can do is wish you godspeed. But if you told us more about your reasons we could potentially suggest alternatives.

Comment: the simple fix is to cast `ctx->data[60] = uint8_t(ctx->bit_len >> 24);`. But the real fix is to use a modern compiler **and** a good crypto library. Modern libraries use SIMD and will be tens or hundreds of times faster than this

Comment: Thanks for the cast suggestion. That solved it.

Comment: Don't put solutions in the question body. Make a separate answer, please. It's the site rules.

Comment: @matead you may wish to check out OpenWatcom, it's an open source compiler that supports pretty much all the systems VC++6 did and is at least still 'maintained'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the compiler in this case

```
ctx->data[63] = ctx->bit_len; // LINE 156 IS HERE!
ctx->data[62] = ctx->bit_len >> 8;
ctx->data[61] = ctx->bit_len >> 16;
ctx->data[60] = ctx->bit_len >> 24;
ctx->data[59] = ctx->bit_len >> 32;
ctx->data[58] = ctx->bit_len >> 40;
ctx->data[57] = ctx->bit_len >> 48;
ctx->data[56] = ctx->bit_len >> 56; // LINE 163 IS HERE!
```

`ctx->bit_len` is a 64-bit type so obviously storing it into a `uint8_t` doesn't work. There's no masking with `0xFF` in those lines like in `digest[i]      = (ctx->state[0] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;`. The only case where it's lacking analysis is `ctx->data[56] = ctx->bit_len >> 56` because the result fits in a `uint8_t`. To get the LSB you need to do an explicit cast so that the compiler knows what you're doing

```
ctx->data[62] = uint8_t(ctx->bit_len >> 8);
```

---

That said, there's no need to copy manually like that, just use `memcpy` and [`ntohll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-ntohll). The code isn't good and using an ancient compiler is even worse. There are lots of good crypto libraries nowadays that use proper SIMD and multithreading like OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

A compiler can be smart enough to check the possible range of an arithmetic expression (in the obvious cases), and this compiler was quite right to issue a warning if it didn't check. This is indeed differently handled by more recent versions of the compiler.

Try this cure: cast the assigned expression to `char`.